# bash: Confusion with redirecting output

Tags: c++, bash, scripting, stdout, stderr

When I execute this command (where fail.cpp is a simple program filled with compiler errors), the errors are not output directly on the screen, but, rather, within the fail.out file:

```
g++ fail.cpp > fail.out 2>&1
```

From my introductory understanding of bash, this makes sense: `>` redirects the program output (stdout, a.k.a. 1) to fail.out, while `2>&1` redirects stderr (a.k.a. 2) to this new place for stdout, which is the file. (?)

But changing the order of the command makes things happen differently:

```
g++ fail.cpp 2>&1 > fail.out
```

Now, the error messages go directly onto the screen, and fail.out is a blank file.

Why is this? It seems like the same idea as above: redirect the errors that this command will produce to stdout (`2>&1`), and redirect that, in turn, to the fail.out file. Is it an order of operations thing that I am missing?

Comment: [Redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29)

Comment: A good explanation in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`2>&1` means "redirect stderr to where stdout is currently connected", and redirections are processed in order from left to right. So the first one does:

1. Redirect stdout to the fail.out file.
2. Redirect stderr to stdout's current connection, i.e. the fail.out file

The second one does:

1. Redirect stderr to stdout's current connection, i.e. the terminal.
2. Redirect stdout to the fail.out file.

Comment: So, just to be sure, `>` means the same thing as `>&1` ?

Comment: No. `>filename` means redirect to `filename`. `>&1` means redirect to where `stdout` is currently connected.

Comment: Ah. Maybe I should ask, "does `>` mean the same as `&1>`?

Comment: `>` is the same as `1>`, `<` is the same as `0<`.